# Print Screen key in i3

Tags: i3

By default, **i3** ignores the <kbd>Print Screen</kbd> key available in most keyboards. How can it be activated?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Everything inside i3 needs to be bound and just a minimal set of keys is added/generated inside the default config. Some keys that are not letters can be represented with its keycodes or keysyms. More about this subject here:

- [i3 User’s Guide - 4.3. Keyboard bindings](https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#keybindings)

Printscreen is the `Print` keysym.

I personally use `gnome-screenshot` to that task, since it can crop images, making life easier. Add the following lines to your `.config/i3/config` or any config file you are using as the `i3wm` main config file.

```
#interactive screenshot by pressing printscreen
bindsym Print exec gnome-screenshot -i 
#crop-area screenshot by pressing Mod + printscreen
bindsym $mod+Print exec gnome-screenshot -a
```

Some people like to use `scrot`. That is up to you to decide :) . Example:

```
bindsym Print exec scrot $HOME/Images/`date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S`.png
```

Comment: The second binding with `Mod1+Print` does not work, but the rest is more than enough.

Comment: [maim](https://github.com/naelstrof/maim) has a rich feature set, including region selection

Comment: Good suggestion :) Will try maim at home too..

Comment: @LuísdeSousa `Mod1` is alt, not your main mod key(Control or Winkey, whatever you have set up). Editing the answer to use main `mod` key. Sorry for the misinformation from my `i3`/`config`

Comment: @ndwildner This is not related to the `$mod`, there is even a sort of error sound that is played.

Answer (score 11):

To expand on @user34720's answer, if `bindsym $mod+Print exec gnome-screenshot -a` doesn't work, pass the `--release` parameter to `bindsym`

`bindsym --release Print exec gnome-screenshot -i`
`bindsym --release $mod+Print exec gnome-screenshot -a`

Comment: --release made it for me because I only wanted to use Print touch